# What is the difference between aboot and boot?

Tags: boot, bootloader

I'm looking through my device and I noticed within `/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name` that there is `boot` and `aboot` partitions. What is the difference between them? Mainly what is `aboot`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The **Application Bootloader** `ABOOT` boots the Android kernel/Recovery kernel.

It is the mechanism to download images onto the device from a host machine (like Windows/Linux PC).

On Samsung devices it runs the ODIN protocol on the device.

The **Primary Bootloader** `boot` part is a computer program that loads the main operating system or runtime environment for the computer after completion of the self-tests.

The PBL acts as a communication engine to download the Secondary Boot Loader (SBL) into the internal RAM and then activates it.

The SBL adds functions for erase and programming of flash memory and EEPROM; it also handles the actual download of new or updated software. This allows a minimum ROM utilization by the PBL

Comment: And what about the SBOOT

Comment: Boot chain goes like this: Power ON --> BootRom/PBL --> SBL --> aboot --> boot | recovery. Boot is kernel (+ ramdisk optionally), not PBL. PBL is stored on SoC, all others are on flash storage partitions.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I wonder if an Android device exists where SBL can be loaded also from an SD card. There would be no danger of bricking any more, and no more hard-or-impossible rootable devices.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica my first question on Android SE (which was marked off-topic) was about breaking the bootloader boot chain in order to boot from SD card. The problem is that everything that loads before Linux kernel is signed with OEM's private keys (check Android Verified Boot), including SBL (or equivalents). And secondly the locations (offsets or filesystem paths) from where to load the next components are hard-coded (except on some develeopment boards/SoCs which provide a switch to change the location). In most cases it's not possible to cope with the both limitations.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica related: [booting Android from SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187183/218526) and [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526) and [Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526) and [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526)