# Downgrading from Lollipop 64-bit to Kitkat 32-bit hard-bricked Micromax Yureka device?

Tags: downgrade, micromax-yu-yureka

**Update**:

I didn't receive any answer here. Look's like my question didn't had enough research to deserve an answer. Here are some updates:

1. I posted the same question on OnePlus forums (I hang around) and received results [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-does-a-phone-downgrade-from-64-bit-lollipop-to-32-bit-kitkat-can-hardbrick-the-device.305328/).
2. I looked for terms `downgrade` on Yureka Forums and out of 159 threads, didn't find any satisfactory [result](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/search/188277/?page=8&q=downgrade&o=date). I found only one argument worthy enough to be mentioned in step 3.
3. A OnePlus forums user mentioned that the 64-bit bootloader could be incompatible with 32-bit Kitkat in the event of downgrading, thereby, resulting a hard-brick. A Yureka forums user mentioned similar thing [here](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/device-bricked-with-lollipop-fastboot.9165/page-2#post-120229).
4. As per this [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/general/guides-bacon-timmaaas-how-to-guides-t2839471) on XDA by a known member of OnePlus forums, and this info of all the partitions in a device [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/info-partition-info.11960/), I can conclude that a **fastboot** type ROM can flash any bootloader and similar partitions required at first stage of booting.
5. I read about bootloader and the name of the involved partitions from [here](http://www.newandroidbook.com/Articles/aboot.html) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/what-is-the-difference-between-aboot-and-boot).

*A flashable ROM zip through recovery can hard-brick which is understandable here*. However, **if a fastboot type 32-bit Kitkat ROM is flashed on Yureka device running 64-bit Lollipop, should it be bricking it?**

**Note**: This question is not meant to be open-ended, inviting discussion/opinion or chatty in nature. My question is only to know : Is there really a technical reason behind the warning or not?

---

**Previously**:

There is a post on Yu forums by a Community Manger [here](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/announcing-the-yu-beta-testing-program.6348/) which says in warning the following:

> Once device is updated with Lollipop (64-bit), downgrading to Kitkat (32-bit) is not supported and may hard-brick the device!

The users on the forum seems to follow the same warning whenever someones creates a thread regarding downgrade to Kitkat. The same warning can be seen on this [website](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-unbrick-and-restore-yu-yureka-to-cyanogen-os-11-stock-firmware/) too.

However, nowhere it seems anyone cared to mention the reason for such hardbrick. May I know why 64-bit to 32-bit is a nightmare for this phone, or for that matter, any phone? Could it be just a gimmick to keep users at latest OS?

Comment: I don't think this question didn't deserve the answer due to not enough research; in fact, you have done better than most of the askers here. But I guess the problem is, there are almost no experienced Yureka users here that can explain this. I just found this question and it looks interesting. On top of that, I also agree that you can also flash the bootloader, rendering the 3rd point a bit strange. Perhaps it's device-dependent or not, I don't have any idea.