# How do I downgrade from Lollipop back to KitKat on Micromax Yureka

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, micromax-yu-yureka

I am having the problem of many application not responding on my Micromax Yureka after upgrading Lollipop Android 5.0. My phone hangs a lot I want to revert back to KitKat.

It was working flawlessley in KitKat. Also, the screen diplay disappers when a call is going on, because of which I am unable to decline the call

Comment: Consider [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106214/downgrade-to-kitkat-on-micromax-yu-yureka) first. Otherwise, follow [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106475/how-to-revert-back-to-kitkat-version-from-upgraded-lollipop-version-in-micromax)

Answer (score 1):

When I searched Google with "`micromax yureka kitkat ROM`", the very first link was a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF6G_cy2YA0) explaining all nicely.

It explains by getting the ROM from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/yureka/orig-development/rom-t3042384) and further instructions are available at that page.

Comment: Thanks but there is a catch here. The XDA thread was last updated in Feb 2015. Lollipop update for this phone came later. I should mention that Kitkat for this device was 32-bit while Lollipop is 64-bit for it. For some reason, you cannot downgrade (see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106546/downgrading-from-lollipop-64-bit-to-kitkat-32-bit-hard-bricked-micromax-yureka-d)). Also, IMO you can't really downgrade usually from Lollipop to Kitkat just by using a zip on Recovery. Even my OPO will brick using this method.