# Where is the "download mode" code stored?

Tags: internal-storage

At least Samsung Galaxy series devices support *download mode*(also known as *Odin mode* or *flash mode*) which usually can be accessed by pressing down specific buttons while powering on the phone. Is this *download mode* on a small separate partition on internal-storage like *recovery mode*? Or is it device-dependent?

Comment: not sure but ,I think it's part of the boot loader it self ,I recall I lost download mode and any other mode when I played with the GANG partition (emmc.img) ,I will come back with a reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how corporate paranoia is going at the time or their design tactics.  A lot of Samsung's download mode is coded within the secondary bootloader. I'm not seeing a non .pdf that I'm happy with but Many references are easily found around the worldwide web. Keywords: secondary bootloader. (edit added detail below)

First attempt to add more details was too long. incase you want more details about the process involved some links at the. Bottom to give a base for research.

Per Samsung knox website refer to PG. 7 under Boot Loader/ Primary Boot Loader/ Secondary Boot Loader: [glossary of terms](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/search/Glossary)

> The SBL adds functions for erase and programming of flash memory and EEPROM; it also handles the actual download of new or updated software. This allows a minimum ROM utilization by the PBL.

Now compare it to what Odin mode does and You will notice similarities. That fact that the bootloader itself can be used as a gateway to obtain sensitive corporate documents. Including the fact that both Qualcomm and Samsung Knox have multiple defense contracts. Makes it tough to find officially supported documentation such as spec sheets or R&D documentation but not impossible.

[IBM Linux boot](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bootload/index.html)

[Android bit fastboot protocols](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/fastboot/fastboot_protocol.txt)

[The new android book process.](http://newandroidbook.com/Articles/aboot.html).

[stack exchange boot and aboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/what-is-the-difference-between-aboot-and-boot)

[Google fastboot protocol](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fastboot/fastboot_phttpsol.txtp://)

Comment: Alright I will go into more detail

Answer (score 2):

Alright.  From what I gather,  it is in either a separate partition "SBL1" and/or it is in a file called sbl.bin.  See [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/triangleaway-reset-flash-counter-tool/) for the partition  names/ locations. And, yes, it is chain fire's triangle away which is featured in the post,  but it seems that the flash counter is stored there,  among other things. So I downloaded a partition viewer,  looked for, and found the two partitions he mentions:
[image]