# How to make and enable a bootable MicroSD?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, boot

I was trying to root some Huawei and Samsung phones, but these do not come with the option to enable the `oem unlock` option, and the partitions and files are in read-only mode. So I was thinking of a workaround, but I don't know if it works or there is a way to do so.

I remember there is a live CD distribution on Linux that enables access to the system and modification or use directly, so is there a way to write an ISO/image/ROM file of a standar version of android or a custom one, to a MicroSD and boot from there to edit the attributes and permissions or even partition or format the internal space?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Booting Android from SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134210/44325) and [Can I root Android by booting from an SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221919/44325).

Comment: bootloader can unlocked by modifying devinfo (older qualcomm) or unsamlock (older samsung) qualcomm devices can be accessed from PC via EDL mode, for exynos, hisilicon, spreadtrum rare low level access exist for some devices. sp flash tool is for mediatek only