# How to remove the Ubuntu Touch kernel at startup?

Tags: linux, bootloader

I have tried the latest Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 5, but it was useless because an exential app doesn't work with Anbox.
So i want to try an Lineage 18.1 unofficial image.
I have installed the image with no problems.
But I cannot remove/erase the ubuntu kernel at start.
I have tried those commands

```
fastboot flash bootloader android/roms/twrp-3.3.1-0-hammerhead.img 
Sending 'bootloader' (13290 KB)                    OKAY [  0.640s]
Writing 'bootloader'                               FAILED (remote: 'invalid bootloader image
')
fastboot: error: Command failed

fastboot flash recovery2 android/roms/twrp-3.3.1-0-hammerhead.img 
Sending 'recovery2' (13290 KB)                     OKAY [  0.640s]
Writing 'recovery2'                                FAILED (remote: 'partition table doesn't exist')
fastboot: error: Command failed

fastboot erase bootloader
Erasing 'bootloader'                               FAILED (remote: 'Partition table doesn't exist
')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

How to remove the kernel at startup?

Comment: you are mixing up bootloader with boot (which is dangerous). furthermore you are mixing up boot with recovery. bootloader is proprietary and is not changed in any way from ubuntu touch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between aboot and boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/what-is-the-difference-between-aboot-and-boot)

Comment: Thanks for the info, so Ubuntu touch has modify the application bootloader?

Comment: So a correct title can be "boot" instead of bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, works on Linux. The phone in example in Nexus 5 so you had to adapt to YOUR phone.
WARNING: , I am not responsible for any kind of damage to your phone, follow this solution at your own risk.
Connect the phone to usb port of a Linux pc, called "host", all commands must be run from this pc.

a)[Download the factory image for Nexus 5](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/hammerhead-krt16m-factory-fb4041cc.zip) then connect the phone to pc WARNING: IS FOR NEXUS 5 HAMMERHEAD, you MUST select another image if use another phone.

ensure this command return the right thing

```
fastboot device
```

b)then extract the zip image, enter in the dir created and run

```
sh flash-all.sh
```

from the computer host

It will reboot in the factory image of Android 4(sic!) and then you can install Ubuntu touch or a "free" Android rom.